# Google play services and network operations

Tags: android, google-play-services

I want to use Google play services version 6.1 and if I use this version I am getting crash on Android 4.4.4 (Google play services installed version 6.1 on this device).

Crash log:

```
 A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x000000b4 (code=1), thread 4143 (ion-ion)
```

I am using this library for network operations:

https://github.com/koush/ion

And this crash happens when I do a network request.

If I update the Google Play services to latest version the crash is disappearing.

What can be cause to this problem?

Comment: why don't you include the latest as a dependency in your project build.gradle so that it gets included as a fallback if a compatible one is not found pre-installed on the device.

Comment: I don't know is everbody using latest version of google play services? Because 6.1 is enough for me.

Comment: yes, just add the dependency and it should be enough. You'll not need to worry about which version is installed and whether or not it is installed on the device using the app.

Comment: Is google play services updating automaticly via Google Play?

Comment: yes google automatically updates it. We can also go and manually update it by searching it in the play store.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my comments on the question, here is how to add the dependency. Change the version to what ever it is you are using to build the project (one that you have on your system and you think is enough)

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
}
```